# вывести переменные из базы через ajax

Tags: php, ajax

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'add_payment.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(php_script_response){
            if(php_script_response=='no') 
                {
                alert('Такой чек уже зарегистрирован');
                }
            else
                { 
                alert(php_script_response);
                }
            }
});
```

Есть примерно такой код.
В php-обработчике идет запрос в БД: если такая запись уже есть, то echo 'no' и alert, что такой чек уже зарегистрирован. 
Если такой записи нет, то она заносится в БД. А во фронтенде я хочу получить информацию о этой зарегенной записи: ее порядковый номер, дату регистрации и вывести это на экран, т.е. несколько переменных вытянутых из базы. 
Так вот как передать php обработчиков данные, какая вообще логика?
P.s. сорри за нубство, только знакомлюсь с технологией ajax

Comment: лучше оперировать `json`-ом. немного не понял. как передать в обработчик данные? верно?

Comment: в обработчик я данные передаю json ом, а вот как из обработчика передать данные вытянутые из БД

Comment: @DmitryKruchko, echo json_encode($response), где $response данные из БД , которые вы хотите вывести

Answer (score 0):

Первое. сделать `datType:json`.

Второе. Все данные которые вы получили в бэкенде, тобишь в вашем php обработчике сделать в виде `json`:

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

На выходе получим `{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}`

В вашем случае все данные помещаете в массив, как видно из примера. и вместо `echo no`, делаете `echo json_encode($data);`.

А после того как пришел ответ достаёте нужные данные. jQ сам распарсит и преобразует в `json`. Вам нужно будет только достать.

Больше [инфо](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.json.php).

Comment: спасибо, все работает!

Comment: @DmitryKruchko отметь вопрос пожалуйста)

Answer (score 0):

На фронте можно сделать такой код :

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'add_payment.php',
                dataType: 'text',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,
                type: 'post',
                success: function(json){
                if(json['add_post']) 
                    {
                    console.log(json.product.id + ':' + json.product.name);
                    }
                else
                    { 
                    console.log(json['error']);
                    }
                }
    });
```

А в `add_payment.php` после всех проверок и добавлений в БД , выбирать данный пост и с помощью `json_encode($response)`, отдавать данные , которые вы хотите вывести на фронте  придерживаясь такой структуры в данном случае :

`{add_post:true,product:{id:1,name:name}}`